# URL Rewrite 2.0 Wildcards - IIS 7.5

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

```
<rule name="WomensSilverBangles" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
    <match url="/Bangles/Silver/Womens.aspx" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Collections/jewellery.aspx?AXSW_CategoryID=Bangles&amp;AXSWFinenessId=Silver&amp;AXSW_GenderID=Womens&amp;MenuName=Jewellery&amp;SiteMapNode=Silver Bangles&amp;depth=2" />
</rule>
```

Can this be written using wildcards?

As you can see, the three variables in the match URL are used in the rewritten URL string.

Comment: Can you be more precise? What are the variables you have, is `Bangles`  always `Bangles` for example?

Comment: Apologies, all three directories (Bangles/Silver/Womens) are variables for each URL.

Comment: Can you try something like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108473/iis-7-5-with-url-rewrite-module-doubles-querystring-params-on-postback?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a while since this question was posted, but there is an excellent article on rewriting [here](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/) and based on that, you could try experimenting with something like this(not tested):

```
    <rule name="3levelcatchall" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="/*/*/*.aspx"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Collections/jewellery.aspx?AXSW_CategoryID={R:1}&amp;AXSWFinenessId={R:2}&amp;AXSW_GenderID={R:3}&amp;MenuName=Jewellery&amp;SiteMapNode={R:2} {R:1}&amp;depth=2" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
```